# __call__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'send' FastAPI on App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gunicorn, fastapi

When trying to host an API on App Engine, the following error keeps coming up. The program used to run on Flask which was working but very slow.

### Error:

```
"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 134, in handle
    self.handle_request(listener, req, client, addr)
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 175, in handle_request
    respiter = self.wsgi(environ, resp.start_response)
TypeError: __call__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'send'
"
```

### Docker File:

```
FROM gcr.io/google_appengine/python

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y ffmpeg

# Create a virtualenv for dependencies. This isolates these packages from
# system-level packages.

RUN virtualenv /env -p python3.7

# Setting these environment variables are the same as running
# source /env/bin/activate.

ENV VIRTUAL_ENV /env
ENV PATH /env/bin:$PATH

ADD requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /app/requirements.txt

# Add the application source code.

ADD . /app

CMD gunicorn -w 4 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker main:app
```

### app.yaml

```
runtime: custom
env: flex
entrypoint: gunicorn -w 4 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker main:app
service: encoder

runtime_config:
  python_version: 3

handlers:

- url: /.*
  script: auto
```

Comment: The error basically says you are trying to run FastAPI as WSGI which is not right and acceptable because FastAPI is only compatible with ASGI.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63099843/how-can-i-fix-fastapi-application-error-on-apache-wsgi)

Comment: Thanks @YagizcanDegirmenci I'll try running it with just Uvicorn

Comment: So it runs, but now I get this error, `"[error] 33#33: *92500 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 216.58.212.244, server: `

Answer (score 38):

As Dustin said I found out that worker class need to be changed. Try the below one.

```
gunicorn -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker main:app
```

Found this on [github issues](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/2154)

Comment: That actually is the most direct answer. Thank you for the link.

Answer (score 7):

App Engine requires your `main.py` file to declare an `app` variable which corresponds to a [WSGI Application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Server_Gateway_Interface).

Since FastAPI is an asynchronous web framework, it is not compatible with WSGI (which is synchronous).

Your best option would be to use a service like [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/), which would allow you to define your own runtime and use an asynchronous HTTP server compatible with FastAPI.

Comment: I am trying to find any info on how to configure Cloud Run to use an asynchronous HTTP server. Can anyone please guide me to the appropriate docs? Thanks.

Comment: @BellaveJayaram Since Cloud Run allows you to use any container image, there is nothing specific required to use an async HTTP server. If there was a particular server you wanted to use and weren't sure how to get started, I'd recommend asking a new question instead of leaving a comment here.

Comment: This is the best answer since it also explains why FastAPI requires a uvicorn worker. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the same issue when I want to deploy a FastAPI app to Heroku. Indeed, you can't use `uvicorn` (which is the ASGI framework that FastAPI is using) with Heroku that uses `gunicorn`.

However, by adding a `uvicorn` worker to `gunicorn` then it works!:

`gunicorn api:app  --bind 0.0.0.0:$PORT --worker-class uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker`

Answer (score 1):

In the [Starlette code](https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/master/starlette/middleware/wsgi.py), I found a reference to [a2wsgi](https://github.com/abersheeran/a2wsgi). And it looks like it is going in both directions (wsgi<>asgi).

I gave it a try and it worked well for me:

```
from a2wsgi import ASGIMiddleware
wsgi_app = ASGIMiddleware(app)
# use this wsgi instead of your app
```

Comment: You might also add ```mount``` call https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/wsgi/?h=wsgi

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by putting `python main.py` as the build command and setting my uvicorn command in the main.py as `uvicorn.run("main:app", host="0.0.0.0", port=8080)`

Comment: It might works for Google Cloud, but might not work in others settings like pythonanywhere.com