# Mapping Google App Engine service to a custom domain path

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, fastapi

I'm creating an API in Python using FastAPI and trying to map a custom service to a path on my domain, the case is as follows:

Default Service: `defaultapp.uc.r.appspot.com` mapped to `api.mydomain.com` and working fine.

Second Service `service2-dot-defaultapp.uc.r.appspot.com`, I want to map it to  `api.mydomain.com/service2/`

---

Default service `dispatch.yaml`

```
dispatch:
  - url: "*/service2/*"
    service: service2
  - url: "defaultapp.uc.r.appspot.com/service2/*"
    service: service2
  - url: "api.mydomain.com/service2/*"
    service: service2
```

---

service2 `service2.yaml`

```
runtime: python37
entrypoint: gunicorn -w 8 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker service2:app
service: service2
```

---

When trying to access service2 from `service2-dot-defaultapp.uc.r.appspot.com` it works fine,

but when I try to access it from `defaultapp.uc.r.appspot.com/service2/` or `api.mydomain.com/service2/` it gives me `{"detail":"Not Found"}`,

I believe it tries to access `/service2/` as a FastAPI path (example: `@app.get('/service2/')` from the default service, and not from `dispatch.yaml`,

---

EDIT:
I've changed the `default service` from an API to a static site so any path given like `/service2/` won't be taken from the API but from the routes in the `dispath.yaml` file, but still the same issue when accessing `defaultapp.uc.r.appspot.com/service2/` or `api.mydomain.com/service2/` it gives me `{"detail":"Not Found"}`

any idea how can I make it work?

Comment: did you deploy your dispatch file? `gcloud app deploy dispatch.yaml` https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/reference/dispatch-yaml

Comment: Just to add, dispatch.yaml file is deployed separately to your app.yaml

Comment: Yes, dispatch.yaml file is deployed and the routes are shown in the services tab.

Comment: App engine is not compatible with ASGI ([see](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63456765/13161155)).